# How do I make ELMAH log to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, logging, elmah

We have integrated [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) with ASP.NET MVC 3, as a way to log application errors. However, we do not yet persist the log. To this end, we'd like to store ELMAH's log entries in MySQL, as we're already using an instance of this database server for other purposes.

How do we configure ELMAH so that it persists its log with MySQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install the NuGet package `ELMAH on MySQL`

> PM> Install-Package elmah.mysql

You have to configure that. from *Elmah.MySql.txt* which is part of the package.

Please note that in order to complete the installation of ELMAH.MySql you will have to do the following:

1. Make sure you have the latest MySQL Connector installed from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ (this is optional, since we already include MySql.Data.dll, if you download the latest connector you don't need our version)
2. Run the Elmah.MySql.sql script against your database
3. Edit your web.config with the correct settings in the elmah  to connect to your database

#### More Information

- [ELMAH on MySQL (requires manual config) 1.2](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah.mysql)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have configured elmah to write to MySQL. In Visual Studio...

1. Install Elmah Nuget Package
2. Install Elmah.MySQL Nuget Package

These two installation make some changes to the web.config file, these are the relevant sections to look for:

```
<elmah>
<security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.MySqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-mysql" />
</elmah>
```

This required a new connection string... elmah already added the template for me, I just needed to put the correct credentials in:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DevDB" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=NZ; Uid=myuserid; Pwd=mypwd" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
<add name="elmah-mysql" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=elmah; Uid=myuserid; Pwd=mypwd" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Make sure EntityFramework provider is correct, if you are using EntityFramework

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

and DbProviderFactories are correct

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

3. Get the relevant SQL Script from here: [elmah.Mysql](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/blob/master/src/Elmah.MySql/MySql.sql) and run the script to create the table and procedures. Also Note that these script by default, create a DB named elmah... if you want to change the db name, make sure it is consistent with your db in the connection string above.

And that's all I had to do to get it running.

**Note**: One thing to watch for is to use lowercase characters for your DB name, in the above connection string, as MySQL DB names are in lowercase... It did work for me initially with uppercase but then it broke and I had to change it.